# GitHub Pages: Redirect custom.domain.tld > user.github.io/project/

Tags: github-pages

As the subject says, I'd like to have my custom domain redirect to a specific project's gh-pages branch.

I can easily get the standard behaviour:

- **custom.domain.tld > user.github.io** (Where the static content lives in github.com/user/user.github.io/ master branch)
- **custom.domain.tld/project/ > user.github.io/project** (Where the static content lives in github.com/project/ gh-pages branch)

But I cannot figure out how to get this:

- **custom.domain.tld > user.github.io/project** (Where the static content lives
  github.com/user/project/ gh-pages branch)

I very much appreciate pointers.

Answer (score 12):

If your `custom.domain.tld` currently points to `username.github.io`, you'll need to remove the CNAME file from your `user.github.io` repository's Master branch. Then, add the same `CNAME` file (with contents `custom.domain.tld`) to your Project repository's gh-pages branch. If you've already set up DNS properly for your `user.github.io` repository, then you won't need to make any changes there, the new CNAME settings on GitHub will take care of it.

One note: when you assign a custom domain (eg custom1.domain.tld) to a User Pages repository, all Project Pages in that User's account will inherit their respective `custom1.domain.tld/project` address, as well as any directly assigned domain (eg custom2.domain.tld).

For example, I have:

- [www.nicksuch.com](http://www.nicksuch.com) > [nicksuch.github.io](http://nicksuch.github.io)
- [www.openkentucky.org](http://www.openkentucky.org) > [nicksuch.github.io/openkentucky](http://nicksuch.github.io/openkentucky) (also accessible at [www.nicksuch.com/openkentucky](http://www.nicksuch.com/openkentucky))
- DNS settings: CNAME - www > nicksuch.github.io (same for both domains, even though one is a [User Page](https://github.com/nicksuch/nicksuch.github.io) and the other is a [Project Page](https://github.com/nicksuch/openkentucky/tree/gh-pages))

More in GitHub's [Setting up a custom domain with Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages).

Comment: Excellent! I just pointed a subdomain to a project subpath - thought it hadn't worked but it just took a few minutes to kick in. Props to GitHub for making this nice and easy, as usual :)

Comment: Wow, I've been trying to do this for HOURS. Turns out I had the right configuration a number of times but didn't wait long enough for it to propagate. Warning to others trying this... WAIT like 10 minutes after all the configurations are done!